# ¿Como conseguir que al seleccionar un item en un Spinner pueda ver lo seleccionado? Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

estoy haciendo un proyecto en android studio y Kotlin pero no entiendo por qué al crear un spinner con los respectivos valores, al pinchar en uno de ellos, se selecciona internamente y funciona todo perfecto, pero no veo el valor que he seleccionado. Os dejo el codigo en el que creo los spinners y les asigno un array de numeros pasados a String.

```
 val array_horas = arrayListOf<String>()

    for (i in 0 until 24){
        if (i < 10){
            array_horas.add("0${i}")
        } else{
            array_horas.add(i.toString())
        }

    }
    val array_minutos = arrayListOf<String>()
    for (i in 0 until 60){
        if (i < 10){
            array_minutos.add("0${i}")
        } else{
            array_minutos.add(i.toString())
        }
    }
    val sp_hora = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.sp_hora)
    val sp_minuto = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.sp_minuto)
    val adapter_hora = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_horas)
    val adapter_minuto = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_minutos)

    adapter_hora.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.texto_lista)
    adapter_minuto.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.texto_lista)
    sp_hora.adapter = adapter_hora
    sp_minuto.adapter = adapter_minuto


    btn_añadir_tarea.setOnClickListener {
        val hora_añadir_tarea = sp_hora.selectedItem.toString()
        
        val minuto_añadir_tarea = sp_minuto.selectedItem.toString()

        ...
```

[image]

Esta es la aplicacion. He añadido un valor a ambos spinners e internamente todo funciona bien, pero no veo lo que he seleccionado

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es saber la posicion del item selecccionado:

```
 val horaPosition =   sp_hora.selectedItemPosition
```

Ahora al tener la pocision del item lo buscas en tu arreglo:

```
val valorHora = array_horas.get(horaPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el indice para que quede seleccionado usando el método:

```
sp_hora.setSelection(<indice de elemento>)
...
...
sp_minuto.setSelection(<indice de elemento>)
```

Por ejemplo, al seleccionar un elemento dentro de `onItemSelected()`  de tu Spinner puedes almacenar el valor de la posiciòn:

```
  var posicHora: Int
  var posicMinuto: Int


  override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
      val text: String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

      posicHora = position
   
   }
```

y posteriormente usar este valor para seleccionar el elemento

```
sp_hora.setSelection(posicHora)
```